# What would be the most effective way to route to an Azure Blob?

Tags: azure, nginx, routes, azure-blob-storage

If I have a public Azure Blob file, e.g. `https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/myblobcontainer/myblobpage.html`

What are my options if I want to route to that page from my own domain?
e.g. if I want to route `mydomain.com/foo/blobpage` to the URL above.

I know that it can be done using Web.confg on Azure WebSites or CloudServices.
As described here [Hide Azure Blob Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516063/hide-azure-blob-url)

Are there any other options? maybe more lightweight? 
I would assume that using the config on an Azure WebSite would come with some sort of overhead and that maybe some nginx proxy or something might be more effective.
So what are the alternatives and how would they compare in terms of scalability to the web config routing?

Answer (score 1):

Today with Azure Storage Account you can configure a custom domain name.
For instructions see:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/

Additionally, If the reason for asking is since web browser through error of "Same-Origin Policy" error, you may just set the CORS roles for the blob:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535601.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In your default or site's config file. give blob container url as `proxy_pass` and set base url of your container as `proxy_set_header Host`

```
location /images {
        proxy_pass https://YOURACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/images;
        proxy_set_header Host YOURACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option that I'd look into will be using HttpHandlers.

Here is a sample handler that could do similar thing:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;

namespace WebApplication2
{
  public class BlobProxy : IHttpHandler
  {
    // Please replace this with your blob container name.
    const string blobContainerName = "files";

    public bool IsReusable
    {
      get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
      // Get the file name.
      string fileName = context.Request.Path.Replace("/blobproxy/", string.Empty);

      // Get the blob from blob storage.
      var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
      var blobStorage = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
      string blobAddress = blobContainerName + "/" + fileName;
      CloudBlob blob = blobStorage.GetBlobReference(blobAddress);

      // Read blob content to response.
      context.Response.Clear();
      try
      {
        blob.FetchAttributes();

        context.Response.ContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType;
        blob.DownloadToStream(context.Response.OutputStream);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        context.Response.Write(ex.ToString());
      }
      context.Response.End();
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the config you need to inject your Http Handler:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="BlobProxy" verb="*" path="/blobproxy/*" type="WebApplication2.BlobProxy"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```